# XCode 4.2 Not Saving Core Data Attribute Minimum Value

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode4.2

Myself and a co-worker have this issue - We have a core data model.  If we go to an attribute in an entity and change its validation to have a minimum value, save the file, quit XCode, and re-open we see that the minimum value we set is no longer set.  This has happened for strings and integers.  Apparently the max value saves fine.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: This is apparently a known issue - http://openradar.appspot.com/10666148   Closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a known issue in XCode 4.2 - http://openradar.appspot.com/10666148